# How do I use CSS/HTML Search Box for Links Section in Google Sites with Apps Script?

Tags: html, css, google-sites

My workplace utilizes a Google Site, and I was able create a CSS dropdown menu to house link information as shown below:
[image]

However, I was wondering if there was also a way to give users a text box at the top they could use to search the entire container faster than having to manually click each section. Something like what [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp) has, but specifically for this container with sub sections in it.

Any help/direction you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Code.GS

```
function doGet() {
var result=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TestSidebar').evaluate();
return result;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Here's the Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Notes for whoever looks at this in the future:
HTML/CSS modified in December 2017, taken from https://codepen.io/alexdevero/pen/avKpLX
Groups are in incremental numbers, along with sub-group and sub-sub-group

group-X
sub-group-X
sub-sub-group-X
sub-sub-sub-group-X

Technically, the CSS stylesheet allows for unlimited nesting. However, if more than 4 groups
are needed, then more sub-groups will need to be defined on the stylesheet

Body beautified at https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/
-->  


<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS sliding multi-level accordion</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300'>


      <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <header role="banner">
        <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav__list">

                <!-- Forms -->
                <li>
                    <input id="group-Delivery/Tracking" type="checkbox" hidden />
                    <label for="group-Delivery/Tracking">
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Forms

                    </label>
                    <ul class="group-list">
                        <li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.google.com/forms/about/" target="_blank">Google Forms</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/" target="_blank">Survey Monkey</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                    <input id="group-links" type="checkbox" hidden />
                    <label for="group-links">
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Links

                    </label>
                    <ul class="group-list">
                        <li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>            
                                        <!-- Final </ul> needed for Nav Pane -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Commenting out; social media links not needed now, but maybe in the future  
<footer><ul class="soc-media"><li><a href="https://twitter.com/alexdevero" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li><li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/deveroalex" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li><li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+AlexDevero" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li><li><a href="http://blog.alexdevero.com" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-globe"></span></a></li></ul></footer>
-->
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS (where I'm assuming any searchbox would go?)

```
<style>
body {

  vertical-align: true;
  font: 100% "Roboto", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/**
 * Hidden fallback
 */
[hidden] {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/**
 * Styling navigation
 */
header {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: true;
  /*max-width: 22.5rem;*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

/**
 * Styling top level items
 */
.nav a,
.nav label {
  display: block;
  padding: .25rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: #012F60;
  vertical-align: true;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #1d1d1d;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-transition: all .10s ease-in;
  transition: all .10s ease-in;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.nav a:focus, .nav a:hover,
.nav label:focus,
.nav label:hover {
  color: #012F60;
  background: #DEB01A;
}

.nav label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/**
 * Styling first level lists items
 */
.group-list a,
.group-list label {
  padding-left: .5rem;
  vertical-align: true;
  font-size: 85%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #8E8E8F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #373737;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #373737;
}

.group-list a:focus, .group-list a:hover,
.group-list label:focus,
.group-list label:hover {
  background: #DEB01A;
}

/**
 * Styling second level list items
 */
.sub-group-list a,
.sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: #012F60;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
}

.sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-group-list a:hover,
.sub-group-list label:focus,
.sub-group-list label:hover {
  background: #DEB01A;
}

/**
 * Styling third level list items
 */
.sub-sub-group-list a,
.sub-sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  background: #8E8E8F;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #575757;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #575757;
}

.sub-sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-sub-group-list a:hover,
.sub-sub-group-list label:focus,
.sub-sub-group-list label:hover {
  background: #DEB01A;
}


/**
 * Styling fourth level list items
 */
.sub-sub-sub-group-list a,
.sub-sub-sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  background: #012F60;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
}

.sub-sub-sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-sub-group-list a:hover,
.sub-sub-sub-group-list label:focus,
.sub-sub-sub-group-list label:hover {
  background: #DEB01A;
}


/**
 * Hide nested lists
 */
.group-list,
.sub-group-list,
.sub-sub-group-list,
.sub-sub-sub-group-list{
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul {
  /* reset the height when checkbox is checked */
  max-height: 1000px;
}

/**
 * Rotating chevron icon
 */
label > span {
  float: +.1rem + left + .1rem;
   vertical-align: true;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease;
  transition: transform .25s ease;
  transition: transform .25s ease, -webkit-transform .25s ease;
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label > span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/**
 * Styling footer
 */
footer {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #050505;
}

.soc-media {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.soc-media li:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.soc-media a {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  -webkit-transition: color .25s ease-in;
  transition: color .25s ease-in;
}

.soc-media a:focus, .soc-media a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
</style>
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Your link to the Drop Down Search example, gives CSS.  You could create an HTML file named **CSS_searchDropDown** and put the CSS in that file.  You are using a scriptlet to include other CSS.  `<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>`  You could add another scriptlet to add the drop down search CSS.  `<?!= include('CSS_searchDropDown'); ?>`

Comment: Hey Sandy, thanks for the reply! Any ideas how I could get the CSS_searchDropDown to filter the other?

Comment: The drop down filter works from a function that shows or hides elements.  Luckily, the menu items in your existing drop down and the one in the W3 example uses `<a>` tags for each menu item.  You need an input field to type into, `<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">` and you need the `filterFunction()`  The filter function is getting a DIV `div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");` which your current HTML doesn't have.  You could try adding an id to `<ul id="myDropdown" class="nav__list">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the solution shown on W3Schools and simply change the list iteration to incorporate one extra level for your categories then you should see some success.

So all you need to do is add an input box and add a filter function to onkeyup.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="filterfunction()"/>
```

And for example you could take their filter function

```
function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

and transform it into something like this for now

```
function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, cat, rows, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    cat = div.children;
    for (i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
        var displayCat = false;
        rows = cat[i].getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (j = 0; j < rows.length; j++){
            if (rows[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                rows[i].style.display = "";
                displayCat = true;
            } else {
                rows[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        if(displayCat){
            cat[i].style.display = "";
            //add some code to expand your list automatically
        }else{
            cat[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

and if you decide to incorporate further categories you can streamline the whole process by changing it to tree iteration.